# advantages of sql management studio?

Tags: sql-server-2008

i just installed sql server 2008 express in order to learn microsoft sql.

why should i install sql management studio express? is it much easier to use this GUI?

Comment: Management Studio makes a lot of things in SQL Server visible, so I'd highly recommend it if you're trying to learn SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default GUI for SQL Server is Management Studio, so you should already have it. If not, it is a free download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en).

It gives you visual access to tables, stored procedure and many of the other features of SQL Server. Not to mention a nice SQL editor with syntax highlighting which also works as a SQL console.

Comment: i dont have the management studio! it didnt come with the 2008 for some reason

Comment: Then download and install it. I added the link to my post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358397/how-to-force-installation-of-management-studio

Answer (score 3):

If you installed SQL Server 2008 Express and got a GUI, that is the SQL Management Studio Express which was included in the installation.

They have a seperate installation fo the Management Studio Express, which will install just the client GUI without the database server, in case you want to use it to connect to a SQL Server database running on another machine.

Comment: i dont have the management studio! it didnt come with the 2008 for some reason

Comment: @every_answer_gets_a_point: it seems like you're saying that you do have some other GUI.  if you don't have Management Studio, what GUI do you have?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358397/how-to-force-installation-of-management-studio