# how to force installation of management studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i already had 2008 express sql server but for some reason it came without management studio. how do i know? because i went programs->sql server 2008 and there was no GUI there.

so i went here to download the entire thing again, supposedly WITH management studio:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7522a683-4cb2-454e-b908-e805e9bd4e28&DisplayLang=en#filelist

after i downloaded and ran the file all i got was a pop up of SQL Server installation center. i had it tell me what i have installed:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Setup Discovery Report

Product Instance    Instance ID Feature Language    Edition Version Clustered
Sql Server 2008 SQLEXPRESS  MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS  Database Engine Services    1033    Express Edition 10.0.1600.22    No
Sql Server 2008 SQLEXPRESS  MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS  SQL Server Replication      1033    Express Edition 10.0.1600.22    No
```

looks like i dont have the GUI installed and i am having a difficult time installing. i dont know why. it just wont install.

i DONT have the GUI. if you think i do have the GUI please tell me where i can find it on my computer.

question:

where can i download the GUI?

Comment: I'm taking it that everything installed correctly and you're not up and running with Management Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here ya go: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en